# DataDetectorsCore crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am looping an array of dictionary and after +- 100, loops console announces me

```
2014-08-14 15:12:35.899 MyApp[1613:60b] DDCache: mmap failed with error 12
2014-08-14 15:12:35.901 MyApp[1613:60b] DataDetectorsCore: mmapping the cache file failed
```

I have never seen this error
Any suggestions? Thanks